# sum of random numbers using angularjs promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
app.service("service1", function ($q) {
    this.number1 = function (num1) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var num1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);
        var result1 = num1;
        deferred.resolve(result1);
        return deferred.promise;
    }
});
app.service("service2", function ($q) {
    this.number2 = function (num2) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var num2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);
        var result2 = num2;
        deferred.resolve(result2);
        return deferred.promise;
    }
});
app.service("addservice", function ($q) {
    this.addition = function (num1, num2) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var result = num1 + num2;
        deferred.resolve(result);
        return deferred.promise;
    }
});
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, addservice, service1, service2) {
    service1.number1().then(function (data) {
        $scope.result1 = data;
    })
    service2.number2().then(function (data) {
        $scope.result2 = data;
    })
    addservice.addition($scope.result1, $scope.result2).then(function (data) {
        $scope.result = data;
    });
});
```

`service1` is used to pass `num1` and `service2` for `num2`. Service3 is used for the sum of those numbers.

How to use `$q.all()` here to sync multiple promises.?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`$q.all()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all) method, it takes either an object or an array of promises and waits for all of them to `resolve()` or one of them to `reject()` and then executes the provided callback function.

```
//In $q as dependecies
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, addservice, service1, service2, $q) {

    //Persist reference of promomise
    var p1 = service1.number1().then(function (data) {
            $scope.result1 = data;
        });
    //Persist reference of promomise
    var p2 = service2.number2().then(function (data) {
            $scope.result2 = data;
        });

    //Pass references
    $q.all([p1, p2]).then(function () {
        //Now pass result 1 and 2
        addservice.addition($scope.result1, $scope.result2).then(function (data) {
            $scope.result = data;
        })
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can **return** both values and use them in a synced promise:

```js
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, addservice, service1, service2) {
  var promise1 = service1.number1().then(function(data) {
    $scope.result1 = data;
    return data;
  })
  var promise2 = service2.number2().then(function(data) {
    $scope.result2 = data;
    return data;
  })

  $q.all([promise1, promise2]).then(function(res) {
    addservice.addition(res[0], res[1]).then(function(data) {
      $scope.result = data;
    });
  })

});
```