# addition of random numbers using angularjs promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
app.service("service1",function($q,$timeout){
  this.number1 = function(num1) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var result1 = Math.floor((Math.random()*5)+1);
    deferred.resolve(result1)
    return deferred.promise;
  }
});
app.service("service2",function($q){
  this.number2 = function(num2) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    //var num2=Math.floor((Math.random()*5)+1);
    var result2 = Math.floor((Math.random()*5)+1);
    // deferred.reject(0)
    deferred.resolve(result2)
    return deferred.promise;
  }
});
app.service("addservice",function($q){
  this.addition = function(num1 , num2) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var result = num1+num2
    deferred.resolve(result)
    return deferred.promise;
  }
});
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, addservice,service1,service2,$q) {
 var p1 = service1.number1().then(function (data) {
  $scope.result1 = data;
  return data;
 });

 var p2 = service2.number2().then(function (data) {
  $scope.result2 = data;
  return data;
 });

$q.all([p1, p2]).then(function () {
 addservice.addition($scope.result1,$scope.result2)
.then(function (data) {
    $scope.result = data;
  })
});
});
```

How to use the `$timeout` so that both the numbers appear after some time?

And how to use `deferred.reject()` for a number greater than 5 that is randomly appearing? We only have to `deferred.resolve()` numbers less than 5.

Comment: your requirement is confusing

Comment: @holydragon How to $timeout to make numbers appear after some time.

Comment: @holydragon How to rejct the numbers which are randomly appearing less than 5?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sum of random numbers using angularjs promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52753232/sum-of-random-numbers-using-angularjs-promises)

Comment: @sh0ber It is. But I have to make these changes to it. And i am stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.service("service1",function($q,$timeout){
  this.number1 = function(num1) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var result1 = Math.floor((Math.random()*5)+1);
    $timeout(function() {
       if (result1 > 5) {
          deferred.reject(result1);
       } else {
          deferred.resolve(result1);
       }
    }, 500);
    return deferred.promise;
  }
});
app.service("service2",function($q, $timeout){
  this.number2 = function(num2) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    //var num2=Math.floor((Math.random()*5)+1);
    var result2 = Math.floor((Math.random()*5)+1);
    // deferred.reject(0)
    $timeout(function() {
        if (result2 > 5) {
           deferred.reject(result2);
        } else {
           deferred.resolve(result2);
        }
    }, 100);
    return deferred.promise;
  }
});
app.service("addservice",function($q){
  this.addition = function(num1 , num2) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var result = num1+num2
    deferred.resolve(result)
    return deferred.promise;
  }
});
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, addservice,service1,service2,$q) {
 var p1 = service1.number1().then(function (data) {
  $scope.result1 = data;
  return data;
 });

 var p2 = service2.number2().then(function (data) {
  $scope.result2 = data;
  return data;
 });

$q.all([p1, p2]).then(function () {
 addservice.addition($scope.result1,$scope.result2)
.then(function (data) {
    $scope.result = data;
  }, function(reason) {
     $scope.result = NaN
  }
});
});
```

Comment: What kind of error ? I've just copied your code and added $timeout and reject part.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
ionic.bundle.js:17922 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module starter due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'starter' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: I've added missing $timeout in service2. Please checkout now.